# Join three tables from activity list

Tags: mysql

I have been working on this sql query, but can't wrap my head around it.
Im trying to fetch all activity from `users_activity` corrospnding to user_id from `users_activity` and `users_followers`. If user1 followes 10 other users, i want the all activity from `users_activity` related to those 10 users, between timestamp `follower_since_timestamp` and now() in table `users_followers`.

```
select
u1.user_name as `user_name being followed`,
u2.user_name as `follower_name that followes`,
ua.*
from  users u1
join users_followers uf on uf.user_id=u1.user_id
join users u2 on u2.user_id = uf.follower_id
join user_activity ua on ua.user_id = u2.user_id
where u1.user_name='demo'
order by ua.activity_timestamp
```

This is what i have so far, but it fetches "backwards". With this query i get all activity that follows demo.

Comment: Can you please share the tables definitions, some sample data, the result you're getting and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59adf/4 as you can se `steve` follows demo and test. and i want the activity for demo and test, and from the fiddle they `uploded image` and `commented`.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what i have so far, but it fetches "backwards".

Then reverse the order ?

```
order by ua.activity_timestamp DESC
```

Will put the newest first

Comment: With this query i get all activity from users that follows demo. I want all activity from the users that demo follows. sorry for confusion